# Javascript: Wildcard regex search

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to filter an array of string with a wildcard regex:

```
// my search key
var myKeyword = 'bar';

// my search list
var strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'barfoo', 'hello', 'java', 'script', 'javascript'];

// my results
var results = [];

// the regexp, I don't understand
var regex = new RegExp(\*/, myKeyword);

// the for loop
for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    if (regex.test(strings[i]) {
        results.push(strings[i]);
    }
}

console.log(results); // prints ['bar', 'foobar', 'barfoo']
```

So how do I fix the regex?

Comment: What do you want to do? Find anything that contains `bar`, no matter where?

Comment: You don't need regex for this. A simple `str.indexOf(myKeyword) > -1` suffices. Regarding the usage of `RegExp`, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it with a regex, do it like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(keyword);
// if you want it case-insensitive:
var regex = new RegExp(keyword, 'i');
```

This will break if the keyword contains any regex-specific characters such as `[` or `*`. You need to write a function to escape these characters if that's a problem for you.

However, you can solve your problem much easier by using `strings[i].indexOf(keyword) != -1` to test if the keyword is in the string or not - without using a regex at all.

Comment: Why `'.*'` peaces are needed?

Comment: The regex is not limited to the start/end of the string. The regex `foo` matches a string containing `foo` anywhere. So would `^.*foo.*$` but there is indeed no reason to make it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @TimPietzcker and ThiefMaster - Yeap, I know )). My question was much more rhetorical.

Comment: Is the *-pattern automaticly used when not extra defined?

Comment: See my previous comment - the regex is not limited to match at the start/end of the string so they are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what exactly you're trying to do here.  Javascript does have literal REs so you could just do:

```
var regex = /foo/;
```

which is just a nicer way of doing:

```
var regex = new RegExp( 'foo' );
```

(but in the second case, the 'foo' could be a string argument being passed in.

You don't need any leading/trailing wildcards on a regular expression.